# Reduce throws "NaN" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sum items in array. While searching Google and Stack Overflow I found that reduce is a good way of summing an array items. But, when there isn't any key value pair reduce throws error as "Nah", so how to deal with it?

My array exam:

```
const array = [
     {
       key: '0',
       value: '10',
       pair: '2' 
   },
     {
      key: '0',
      value: '10' 
   }
];
```

So from above, I need to calculate all the key values including pair. But when I use it on reduce it gives NaN as the second object doesn't have 'pair',

How to deal this?

My code:

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a + ((+b.key)+(+b.value)+(+b.pair)), 0)
```

So how to handle this "NaN"

Comment: How to handle this is for you to say. How *do you* want it to be handled?

Comment: I want everything needed to be summed @trincot

Comment: Another thing that i see over your code its that value, pair and key fields are strings, if you want to sum numbers an be interpreted as math expression  just parseInt() the fields  .

Comment: @altoqueperro, the OP already deals with that, using the unary plus (preferred way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the new nullish coalescing operator, or since you know these are either numbers or non-existent and you want to us `0` in the non-existent case, the logical `||` operator:

```js
const array = [
     {
       key: '0',
       value: '10',
       pair: '2' 
   },
     {
      key: '0',
      value: '10' 
   }
];

const result = array.reduce((a, b) => a + ((+b.key)+(+b.value)+(+(b.pair ?? 0))), 0);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                         Or   +(b.pair || 0)
console.log(result);
```

You don't need all of those `()`, though:

```js
const array = [
     {
       key: '0',
       value: '10',
       pair: '2' 
   },
     {
      key: '0',
      value: '10' 
   }
];

const result = array.reduce((a, b) => a + ((+b.key)+(+b.value)+(+(b.pair ?? 0))), 0);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                         Or   +(b.pair || 0)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There **has** to be a good dupetarget for this, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Not a big difference but I would use `(+b.pair || 0)` rather than `+(b.pair || 0)`

Comment: @Barmar - Yeah, just be sure **not** to use `(+b.pair ?? 0)` (which is part of why I left the `+` outside the parens).

Comment: Yes, i have used ```(+b.pair || 0)``` which works perfectly !

Comment: Thanks bud @T.J.Crowder I have used ```(+b.pair || 0)``` instead of using ```(+(b.pair || 0))``` Hope it wont affect

Comment: @PatriciaD19 - `(+b.pair || 0)` works. What you **don't** want to do is `(+b.pair ?? 0)`, because `+b.pair` will be `NaN` if `pair` doesn't exist, and the nullish coalescing operator doesn't consider `NaN` nullish. So `(+b.pair || 0)` works, `+(b.pair || 0)` works, and `+(b.pair ?? 0)` works, but **not** `(+b.pair ?? 0)`. You don't need all those `()` though, I've added an example removing the unnecessary ones:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a + ((+b.key||0)+(+b.value||0)+(+b.pair||0)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `sum` of the `values` in each iteration, and check if the value is a `Number`:

```js
const array = [
  { key: '0', value: '10', pair: '2' },
  { key: '0', value: '10' }
];

const res = array.reduce((a, b) => 
  a + Object.values(b).reduce((acc, value) => acc + (isNaN(value)?0:+value), 0)
, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I feel above answer by @T.J. Crowder  is better ?

Comment: @PatriciaD19 it depends on your requirements and inputs. This is another way to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap`, `Object.values` and `reduce`. (Assuming that we want sum of all the existing key values).

```js
const array = [
     {
       key: '0',
       value: '10',
       pair: '2' 
   },
     {
      key: '0',
      value: '10' 
   }
];

const sum = array.flatMap(Object.values).reduce((sum, cur) => +cur + sum, 0);

console.log(sum)
```